# A strange phrase in YouTube video, could you please explain it?

Tags: american-english, expressions

I'm watching CMU Database Systems course. In this video:

https://youtu.be/QKNISiRJF-4?t=1841

... at 30:58 speakers says something like "These are numbers that should be (mind for low???)". I've never heard an expression like this before. Could you tell me please, what the sentence actually is and what does it mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

He is saying "these are the numbers you should be [mindful](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mindful) of".  Another way to say that is "these are the numbers that are important" or "these are the numbers that you should pay attention to."

Mindful

1. bearing in mind
2. inclined to be aware

Comment: Including the definition in your answer, in addition to a link to the source, makes for a more useful answer.

Comment: Sorry, fat-fingered...